# What happens when an on-hold question is edited and nominated for reopening by the OP?

Tags: discussion, reopening-questions

My question was put on hold as too broad, understandably.

Now, I've edited it and am fully confident that it is no longer broad, and have nominated it for reopening.

What happens now? Do all on hold questions go into a queue for reviewing, or just ones nominated to be reopened?

Do I need multiple reopen votes? I'm just trying to figure out what happens from the perspective of the person who will - if I've done my job right - be reopening it.

Answer (score 3):

The first edit on a question that is "On Hold" automatically sends the question to the "Reopen Review Queue" where members with more than 3k reputation can vote to leave it closed or reopen it. When 2 members choose "Leave closed" it disappears from the queue, though the reopen votes stay. People can still vote to reopen from the question page itself. When 5 members vote "Reopen" it will get reopened. Reopen votes decay after 14 days. The same rules apply to close votes. A question where the OP votes to reopen will be sent to the queue, too.

Currently your question has 1 reopen vote and therefore needs 4 more. As it's currently the weekend you should expect less activity, which means that it will take some time until enough members with the appropriate reputation, the time and the inclincation to review the reopen queue have looked at it.